# Java - Printing a message when data in file exceeds limit?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, queue

So I've got my code working, it's not pretty but it does the job :)

Now I want to write a piece of code that stops the data from being printed if there are 19 or more pieces of data in the text file and then display a message saying "Invalid input" for example.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
package stackandqueue;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackAndQueue {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Create three empty stacks of Bays.
    // Bay 1 linked list
    Queue<String> bayoneStack = new LinkedList<String>();
    // Bay 2 linkd list.
    Queue<String> baytwoStack = new LinkedList<String>();
    // Bay 3 linked list
    Queue<String> baythreeStack = new LinkedList<String>();

    Queue<String> bayloadStack = new LinkedList<String>();

    System.out.println("***********************************************");

    // Open and read text file
    String inputFileName = "PodData4.txt";
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("PodData4.txt");

    // Create the FileReader object
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);) {
        // Sort the data into the relevant linked list by type F, T or P.
        String[] strings = br.readLine().split(",");
        for (String str : strings) {
            switch (str.charAt(0)) {
            case 'F':
                bayoneStack.add(str);
                break;
            case 'T':
                baytwoStack.add(str);
                break;
            case 'P':
                baythreeStack.add(str);
                break;
            default:
                // In-case of invalid input

            }

            System.out.println(str);

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle exception;
    } finally {
        fileReader.close();
    }
    // Prints out the linked list stacks showing all Bays.
    System.out.println("***********************************************");

    System.out.println("Bay 1:Food: " + bayoneStack.toString());
    System.out.println("Bay 2:Technical: " + baytwoStack.toString());
    System.out.println("Bay 3:Personal: " + baythreeStack.toString());

    }
    }
```

Comment: What does `pieces of data` mean?

Comment: Well I have a text file with (pieces of) data in it which look like this, T13, D42, D11, P52, T67, T21 etc. Each one is one bit of data to be sorted into the relevant queue which it doe's but I want a message to be displayed saying Invalid input due to too much data. Also if it could say Invalid input when there is an empty text file that would be great too!

Comment: Since you catch the IOException you can show an error in there as well as your default situation in switch case... Also you can check the sizes of Queues by .size() method, and if its bigger than 19 you can show your message

Answer (score 1):

Considering your array of `String` contains the data in your file, you could simply use the length of this array to determine whether it exceeds the limit. For example:

```
String[] strings = br.readLine().split(",");
if(strings.length >= 19) // Check whether there is more data then you expected
{
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
    return; //Return from the main function, stop the program
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. So I've done that but I tried to add it so it wouldn't accept files with zero data aswell but I seem to have stepped into a minefield even though it should be simple.